# How do I add text to a response from a remote URL in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

I have the following *server* in **NGINX** and it works fine. But, I am wondering is it possible to add text to a response from a remote URL where hosts my `before_body.txt` and `after_body.txt`? Is there any way to tackle this?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /storage/path;
    index index.html;

    server_name  test.domain.com;

    location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     add_before_body /src/before_body.txt;
     add_after_body /src/after_body.txt;
     autoindex on;
    }

   location /src/ {
     alias /storage/path/content/;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved with replacing the `alias` as follows:

```
location /src/ {
     proxy_pass https://externalserver.com/;
}
```